# Using for loops to add Options within a select PHP

Tags: php

I want to add all the months in one go, without manually entering them. Since months have a numeric value (1 - 12) i thought it'd be easy to do it like this:

```
$monthsel = $form->add(new jqmSelect('month', 'month', ''), true);
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    $month = strtotime("F", $i);
    $monthsel->add(new jqmOption("$month", $month, false));
    $monthsel->attribute('data-native-menu','false');
}
```

However, the month gets displayed inside the select like this:

```
21601
21602
21603
21604
21605
21606
21607
21608
21609
21610
21611
21612
```

I believe that is a timestamp for a month?

Well regardless of what it is, i'd like the full name of the month to appear inside the Selects.

Comment: What class is the $form variable an instance of ? what's the jqmSelect class ? How do you render the result ? Please pay attention and give details when asking questions, this cannot possibly be answered.

Comment: um. im using jqmphp. Its an html generator. It shouldn't factor in on why im having a problem with the date. Therefore this question can be answered.

Comment: You're asking a question about why something is not rendered the way you want, and you think the libraries you use to do the rendering "shouldn't factor in on why it works the way it works" ? Then I'm sorry to say that you think wrong. Please provide at least a link to the jqm library and the relevant part of your rendering code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because `strtotime` expects a timestamp. `$i` is not a timestamp and so `strtotime` would see it as 1 second. So your best bet would be to do something such as:

`strtotime("F", date('Y-' . $i . '-m'));`

This is just one of many was to accomplish this. Your could also have an array like:

`$months_array = array('January', 'Feburary', ...);`

The doing:

`$month = $months_array[$i - 1];`